Short title running and Author running in article class
I try to add short title running on the even pages and author running on the odd page in a document, using this code:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\bf THE TITLE}

\author{FIRST AUTHOR\footnote{{\tt e.mail@address.com} Address} 
       \and SECOND AUTHOR\footnote{second author address}
       \and THIRD AUTHOR\footnote{third author address}}
\date{~}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{The short title}{F. Author S. Author T. Author}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}

The output is:



As can be observed, the author is inserted on the top of the even pages (as on the odd pages) and not the short title as I want.
I really don't know how to fix it, by keeping the same layout of the document (margins, width, length etc.) as for the article class.
Any help would be appreciated.

The left head set with \markboth is used in two-sided documents. You can try the option twoside but the geometry of even pages will be reversed.

I think this answer can help you.

@jlab Thank you, I saw that answer, but I couldn't deal with the solution there. Using twoside I encountered the same problem with the geometry changing and that's why I gave up.

Set your headings using fancyhdr, and you can include ifoddpage to see whether you're on an odd or an even page (called runningheads below).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\bfseries THE TITLE}

\author{FIRST AUTHOR\footnote{\texttt{e.mail@address.com} Address} 
       \and SECOND AUTHOR\footnote{second author address}
       \and THIRD AUTHOR\footnote{third author address}}
\date{~}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,ifoddpage}
\fancypagestyle{runningheads}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
  \fancyhead[L]{% Left header
    \checkoddpage% Update \ifoddpage
    \ifoddpage
      F.~Author, S.~Author, T.~Author% Odd pages
    \else
      The short title% Even pages
    \fi
  }%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}% Right header
}

\pagestyle{runningheads}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}


Thank you, it works well.

It is almost never necessary to check for even/odd pages with fancyhdr, as you can use the E and O flags.

@PietervanOostrum: Yes; I may have recalled (incorrectly) that there was a warning issued when not in twoside mode.

Actually you probably were correct. However, nowadays fancyhdr has a [twoside] option that solves this.

Here is a simplified version of Werner's solution, using fancyhdr E and O options instead of \ifoddpage. Also it doesn't define a new pagestyle as this isn't necessary in this example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\bfseries THE TITLE}

\author{FIRST AUTHOR\footnote{\texttt{e.mail@address.com} Address} 
       \and SECOND AUTHOR\footnote{second author address}
       \and THIRD AUTHOR\footnote{third author address}}
\date{~}

\usepackage[twoside]{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
  \fancyhead[LO]{F.~Author, S.~Author, T.~Author} % Left header
  \fancyhead[LE]{The short title} % Left header
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}% Right header

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}


Thank you very much!
